# Jquery Hover image and Alt text - execution order?

Tags: jquery

I've a very simple jQuery script to change an image and display the alt text when a thumbnail is hovered over.

Both image and Alt text display in the same div. The code works but the text displays before the image changes and so briefly resizes the div for long alt text:

```
$("#thumbwrapper li img").hover(function(){
    $('#main_img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
    $("#desc").html( $(this).attr("alt") );
});
```

I need to order these two so the IMAGE changes 1st and then the alt text. I'm guessing I need to nest a second function but don't know how.
This is my guess of nesting function() but it just breaks the alt text changing:

```
$("#thumbwrapper li img").hover(function(){
    $('#main_img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''),function(){
        $("#desc").html( $(this).attr("alt") );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because img is getting loaded async so event if you set its src before writing the alt into the div, the load event ends after.
You can use a setTimeout function (quick and dirty) or use the img load event:

```
var image =new Image();
image.src="your path";
image.load=function(){
   $("#desc").html( $(this).attr("alt") );
}

image.load();

//add the image into the DOM here
```

This is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: I'm interested to ask: would this work in all browsers? I've had some REALLY interesting results in Internet Explorer (uduh!) when it couldn't verify things like an `Image()`'s `.complete` property...otherwise, nice clean solution!

Comment: I didn't test this in older IE versions, but i can say this works very good with all modern browsers (including mobile browsers)

Comment: @Simon Coombes please consider accepting the answer if this is what you were looking for

Comment: @andreapier this looks exactly like the solution but being a newbie to JQuery I'm unclear how this works with replacing the src attribute of the image.

Comment: Well. just give me i jsfiddle.com example and i'll edit it to fit your needs

Comment: As it stands the code is literally 4 lines:
`<script type="text/JavaScript">
$("#thumbwrapper li img").hover(function(){
    $('#main_img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', '')),(function(){
 $("#desc").html( $(this).attr("alt") );
 });
});
</script> <script type="text/JavaScript">
$("#thumbwrapper li img").hover(function(){
    $('#main_img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', '')),(function(){
 $("#desc").html( $(this).attr("alt") );
 });
});
</script>`
It's very fast n very simple. How can the img load event be tied in? Would a simple delay be better?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add a delay(500) call before showing the text? Like this:

```
$("#desc").delay(500).html( $(this).attr("alt") );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work faster for you if you preload the image:

```
var image = new Image(); image.src = // image source
```

This will cause the browser to download the image and that should be no lag time when you set the src of the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a classic case of Javascript image preloading problems, like most of the other answers seem to be aiming at. I often use the preload functionality in Javascript, and I just wanted to give my 2cents answer as another option, hope it helps! :)

```
$("#thumbwrapper li img").hover(function()
{
    // prepare the variables...
    var source = $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', '');
    var description = $(this).attr("alt");

    // start the preload...
    // might think of putting a loader message in your app somewhere in case
    // this takes longer than expected...
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function()
    {
        $('#main_img').attr('src', source);
        $("#desc").html(description);
    };

    // finally, start the preload...
    img.src = source;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, some more general advice : study the jQuery API rather than guessing (you can't give attr() three arguments), and go and read up on "chaining".

If you don't understand chaining then you're going to write a lot of jQuery the wrong way.  A simple explanation is here : [Quick Guide: Chaining in jQuery](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/)